# Javascript Axios How to return status 404 from function

Tags: javascript, axios

I had a problem how to return axios status from function. I have found the solution but I feel there is a better option. I have tried many ways but only this one works. Is this solution correct? or I should find another?

```js
export const getPerson = async (patient) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/user',patient)
    return res.data
  } catch (err) {
    return err.response.status
  }
};
```

```js
onSubmit = async () =>{
        await getPerson({id:this.state.id})
        .then(data => {
            if(data === 404){
                this.setState({errorStatus:data})
            }
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
```

Also Can someone explain to me why in this example then and catch execute simultaneously.

```js
onSubmit = async () =>{
        await getPerson({id:this.state.id})
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch( err => console.log(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach in my opinion would be to have the same object structure returned in both cases.  The difference would be in what the object contains.

```
export const getPerson = async (patient) => {
   try {
     const res = await axios.post('/api/user',patient)
     return {data: res.data, status: 200}
   } catch (err) {
     return {data: {}, status: err.status}
   }
};
```

With this, you can just check the error status if you want to determine if data is valid or not based on the response status, with checking the status.

```
if (data.status === 200) {
   console.log(data)
}
else {
   this.setState({errorStatus: data.status})
}
```

For your question, i suppose that the post request throws an error, so it starts with the `.then()` function and then the post request throws an error, which is caught by `.error()`

Comment: Thanks. It looks more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Why not just let the error flow to the calling function if you want to handle the error there?

```
export const getPerson = patient => axios.post('/api/user', patient)

onSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await getPerson({ id: this.state.id })
    console.log(res);
  }
  catch (err) {
    this.setState({ errorStatus: err.response.status })
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep axios action in another file.

Comment: Then just write `export const getPerson = patient => axios.post('/api/user', patient)` in that other file

Comment: Okay. I got it now. Thank you for your time